# DataGridView Row Height Autosize

Tags: c#, datagridview, row, height, autosize

I am using a `DataGridView` in C# .NET 3.5 and I want the height of all rows set to `AutoSize`.

I set `WrapMode = true` but am still not getting the height to autosize.

Answer (score 60):

`DataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells`

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autosizerowsmode.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Yoshi +1. You can also set the properties of the grid at design time using the same properties.

Answer (score 5):

if you want to change only for particular row :

```
 int j = Rowindex;
 datagridview1.AutoResizeRow(j, DataGridViewAutoSizeRowMode.AllCells);
```

Answer (score 2):

DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders;

is a better choice, if you want to keep same width of columns.

Comment: As long as `DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode` does not have a definition for `DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders` it must be `AllCellsExceptHeaders`.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the "DefaultCellStyle" -> WrapMode = true
in Design, easy!