# Select-Deselect images present in the Panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, groupbox

Hello i am having `groupbox` which contain `panel`, in that panel i have added multiple images dynamically, i want to select and deselect that image thumbnails as per requirement, so please help me out my groupbox looks like as .  [image]

how can i select or deselect multiple images from this...
**here is my code**

```
 private void AddFacesToPictureBoxes(List<PictureBox> pictureBoxes)
        {
            foreach (var pic in pictureBoxes)
                this.pnlFacetbox.Controls.Add(pic);
                this.gbFacets.Controls.Clear();
                this.gbFacets.Controls.Add(pnlFacetbox);
        }
```

Comment: i have just added 3-4 lines code, in which i added images into panel from list picture box. i think need to work on panel UI..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Winform datagrid has inbuilt feature of checkbox column,image column and in addition it can be easy scrollable.I hope it exactly your looking for

[image]

Comment: Hey but i want image preview also with checkbox right corner to it...then what should i do??

Comment: first column will ve list of checkbox while in second column your going to display list of images(in Imagelist as shown above),for that load your image for grid.rows[index].cell[1].value=image; use to autosize row http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948097/datagridview-row-height-autosize

Comment: ohk means first we have to create this grid view with data means images and checkboxes and then need to bind with panel..m right??

Comment: why to bind with panel now,you can directly set image to grid,as i have mention in my previous comment.grid.rows[index].cell[1].value=image,if it work for you,pls mark it as an answere.