# Winforms datagridview - exclude column from row autosizing

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, autosize

I have dataGridView with 3 columns in my C# winforms application. Two with text and one with image. I want to use row autosize for multiline text in first two columns, but not for image. Is that possible.

Comment: are you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666582/datagridview-autofit-and-fill

Comment: Yes, but thats for column width. I need row height.

Answer (score 0):

ok Try this:

[DataGridView Row Height Autosize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948097/datagridview-row-height-autosize)

or this:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/fea3dcff-5447-450a-8f7c-bb1c4f63371d/merging-cells-in-datagridview?forum=winformsdatacontrols